# Unable to merge the rows in a table properly

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

Unable to merge the rows in a table properly. Want to fix cells with 'KKK'. Please advise. Following is my code.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\tiny
\label{Label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{KKK}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{XXX}}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{XXX}}   &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{XXX}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{KKK}}\\
    \hline
    & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XXX}}   & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & 
\textbf{XXX} &\\ 
    \hline
    YYY & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\checkmark \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\checkmark \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\checkmark \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\checkmark \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular}\\ 
    \hline          
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why does your last row have many single cell tabulars nested in a table?  Does this compile without error?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes it does compile. I need single cells to represent 'selected or not selected' cases. Want to fix only cells with 'KKK'. Just changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `hline` always stretches the entire length of the table.  If you don't want that, then you want `cline`, `\cline{2-10}` in this case.

But as I commented, there's no real point in a cell containing `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \end{tabular}`, and `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\checkmark \end{tabular}` might as well be `\checkmark`.

Have you looked into the booktabs package?  It's devoted to making it easier to create nice looking tables.  Their approach to your table would be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\tiny
\label{Label}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{KKK}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{XXX}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{XXX}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{XXX}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{KKK}}\\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}
    & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} &
    \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{XXX} &\\ 
    \midrule
    YYY & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

with output:

[image: code output]

That output could probably be improved even more, but we'd need to know more of the context.